# Sony Vaio Touchpad Malfunction (always registering a touch)

Tags: mouse, windows-8.1, touchpad, sony-vaio

After I brought my laptop to school (purchased 2 weeks ago), I found my touchpad was misbehaving in various ways. First, the touch pad would zoom instead of move on Google Chrome. Then, the touchpad would jump to top-right corner occasionally. Now, the problem manifests itself as the touchpad always freezing, and the Synaptic animation registering pressure all the time (green blob). If I fiddle with the touchpad settings, I found forced zooming was disabled if I disable zoom gesture. I also checked the Synaptic pressure graph. The conclusion is that the touchpad always registers a touch.

After I uninstalled Synaptic driver, the touchpad responds, but will always jitter around, even if I hover my finger above it and not touch the touchpad at all.

I am using Sony Vaio Fit 15e on Win8.1.

Comment: RMA the device, a new laptop should not have such issues.

Comment: I believe it is the interaction of bloatware and touchpad driver. I reinstalled driver and restarted the system twice and the situation got better. Also, touchpad problem never happened on UEFI or a Linux system

Comment: I guess it is Win8.1 update problem. I will answer my own question after I fixed it. http://www.ryukent.com/2013/11/fixed-install-synaptics-touchpad-driver-windows-8-1/